# Angular auth guard not redirecting to login

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, authentication, angular-material

I would like some help with troubleshooting an issue I have in my app. I am trying to create a functionality, that if the user is not loged in if he tries to access any url of the app he should be redirected to login.

I have created a auth guard but it somehow does not redirect me or users to [www.my-domain.com/login](http://www.my-domain.com/login) but it rather stays on the [www.my-domain.com/dashboard](http://www.my-domain.com/dashboard) but it shows an empty page...

where is the issue in my code?

Here is the **auth.service.ts** code:

```
login(): Observable<User> {
    const params = new HttpParams().append('param', 'value');
    return this.http.get<User>(`${environment.apiUrl}someurl` + location.search, {params}).pipe(
      tap((response: any) => {
        if (response && response.token) {
          localStorage.setItem('TOKEN_KEY', response.token);
          localStorage.setItem('username',response.user_name);
          localStorage.setItem('useremail',response.user_email);
          this.setAuthToken(response.token);
          this.isLoggedIn = true;
        } else {
          this.router.navigate(['/login']);
          return;
        }
      }),
      catchError(error => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
        return throwError(error);
      })
    );
  }

  isLogedIn() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('TOKEN_KEY');
    return !!token;
  }
```

Here is my **auth.guard.ts** code:

```
export const authGuard = () => {
  const authService = inject(AuthenticationService);
  const router = inject(Router);

  if (authService.isLogedIn()) {
    return true;

  } else {
    console.log('Not logen in');
    return router.parseUrl('/login');
  }

};
```

Here is my app-routing.module.ts code:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '',   redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, title: 'Login', },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    title: 'Dashboard',
    canActivate: [authGuard],
    canMatch: [() => localStorage.getItem('TOKEN_KEY') != null]
  },
  {
    path: 'customers',
    component: CustomersComponent,
    title: 'Customers',
    canActivate: [authGuard],
    canMatch: [() => localStorage.getItem('TOKEN_KEY') != null]
  },
  {
    path: 'customers/customers/:id',
    component: CustomerComponent,
    title: 'Customer',
    canActivate: [authGuard],
    canMatch: [() => localStorage.getItem('TOKEN_KEY') != null]
  },

];
```

Where is my mistake? what could I have done diferently?

Comment: Can you share you routing config

Comment: Do you see the log `Not logen in` in the console ?

Comment: Do you clear your localstorage?

Comment: You are not navigating, you just call `parseUrl`. Use `navigateByUrl` for example.

Comment: @TonyNgo I have added routing.module.ts code

Comment: @CharlieV Yes, I am clearing it with logout function in authservice

Comment: @PhilippMeissner where exactly?

Comment: Why not use: this.router.navigate(['/login'])?

Comment: @CharlieV where?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your **auth.guard.ts** code:

Try this instead

```
else {
    console.log('Not logen in');
    return router.navigateByUrl('/login');
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the difference?

Comment: `parseUrl` breaks down a URL string into its individual components, such as the protocol, host, path, query params etc, you can use that to extract specific values from the URL.  `navigateByUrl` changes state of a web application to whatever URL you have specified